# Graphs user object

Tags: graph, powerbuilder

Using PowerBuilder, has anyone here tried to copy the graph onto the clipboard?

I saw that the graph object does not have a built in COPY function.

Thanks in advance for all that will answer. It will be a big help for me..

Answer (score 0):

The graph.Clipboard() function does what I believe you're asking, from help: "Replaces the contents of the system clipboard with a bitmap image of a graph."

BTW, to find this I went to PB help, Help Topics button, Contents tab, expand in tree (varies a little between versions) Objects and Controls, System Object Properties..., double clicked Graph object, clicked the Functions button and scanned the list of graph functions and their descriptions. This method is helpful when trying to find a function when you know the object.

Good luck,

Terry.